# How do I run a puppet exec if a condition met?

Tags: exec, puppet, redhat, trend

Just to give some details - building on AWS, using Puppet to handle DSC, and have bootstrapped Puppet so that it provisions, and installs Puppet on the newly provisioned node.

I've been working with Puppet for a little amount of time now, and I find myself wanting to write a module that only executes on creation of a vm.

My particular use case is that I want to install antivirus (specifically, Trend Micro Deep Security) onto a newly provisioned node, automagically via Puppet.

The script to run this only requires a download, a run, and a couple of TMDS specific commands to activate itself etc.

If I use Puppet, it will do this on every run (download, try to install, try to activate) which is definitely not what I want.

However, I don't think that Puppet 'knows' about Trend Micro, or how to get it, or the URL etc. So I can't use something like:

```
  service { "trend micro":
    ensure => running,
    ensure => present,
  }
```

Doing some research, and looking at [blog posts](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/exec-onlyif.html), I know that the structure of my code should be something along the lines of (I know it's not correct):

```
exec {'function_name':
  # the script that downloads/installs/activates etc.
  command => '/path/to/script.sh', 
  onlyif  => systemctl service_trendmicro, 
  # which system should return 0 or 1 for pass/fail - I only want it to exec on 0 ofc.
}
```

My question is therefore: How do I put this together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Puppet to run scripts, as you're doing. However, you end up with the same problems you would have if you were running the scripts without Puppet: it's hard to make them idepotent, they're annoying to maitain and they're not portable to other platforms.

There appears to be [Chef cookbooks](https://github.com/deep-security/chef) and [Ansible Playbooks](https://github.com/deep-security/ansible) provided by the company to install the agent. These should give you a rough idea of what to do with Puppet.

From looking at the Ansible playbook, it's pretty easy to turn it into equivalent Puppet code:

```
exec {'download Trend RPM':
  command => '/bin/wget https://app.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com:443/software/agent/RedHat_EL7/x86_64/ O /tmp/agent.rpm --quiet',
  creates => '/tmp/agent.rpm',
}
->
package {'ds_agent':
  ensure   => 'installed',
  provider => 'rpm',
  source => '/tmp/agent.rpm',
}
~>
service {'ds_agent':
  ensure => running,
  enable => true,
}
```

I just did a quick check on a CentOS 7 VM and it seemed to work for me:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for centos7.vm in environment production in 1.06 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Exec[download Trend RPM]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[ds_agent]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[ds_agent]/enable: enable changed 'false' to 'true'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Service[ds_agent]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: Applied catalog in 8.45 seconds
```

I'd recomend looking into the existing Ansible playbook and seeing how to turn the rest of the setup steps: https://github.com/deep-security/ansible/blob/master/playbook/

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I didn't check over the weekend :)
I'm pretty new to Puppet, but this looks more than doable - let me give this a go, and let me see if I can get it to work in Puppet!
Will report back when I've tested it. Thanks dude!

Can I just check that I've understood this correctly?
The Exec obviously downloads the agent rpm, but will this happen every run? Or does creates => mean that it will check to ensure that it's not there, before downloading?
In Puppet, even if it's not a recognised package, we can still create a new one, and Puppet will look for that package with...

Comment: (cntd from previous) the location that is given to it (in this case, /tmp/agent.rpm)... 

Sorry for all the questions, I'm trying to get my head around it, I come from an OOP background, and want to try and analogise things to what I already know!

Thanks :)

edit: Oh and thanks for linking me to the Ansible/Chef cookbooks, I had no idea that the code structure was (at least semi) transferable with a little work. Very very useful.

Comment: Hey that implementation worked perfectly! I'll have a look through the Ansible cookbook and see if I can't come up with anything else! thanks very much for this! Resolved! :)

Comment: Yep! The full lowdown on all parameters are here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html, I'd also recommend looking at the https://puppetlabs.com/download-learning-vm learning VM which teaches some concepts! :)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this module: https://github.com/echocat/puppet-redis

It installs Redis from source. So it downloads, installs, configures, and starts the service. Essentially, its functionality is equivalent to the one you are seeking.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I'm not quite sure this is the implementation that would work best in the environment...